# All subsets of an array recursively only in one function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've managed to do this in two recursive functions. But am really curious, is it possible to use both recursions in one function...

Here is a task of an exercise and a hint:

> Write a function called `subsets` that will return all subsets of an array.
>
> Examples below.

> Hint: For subsets([1, 2, 3]), there are two kinds of subsets:
>
> 1. Those that do not contain 3 (all of these are subsets of [1, 2]).
> 2. For every subset that does not contain 3, there is also a corresponding
>    subset that is the same, except it also does contain 3.

Here is my solution with 2 recursives, examples of the task are included:

```js
let arr = []
console.log(JSON.stringify(subsets(arr))); // [[]]
arr = [1]
console.log(JSON.stringify(subsets(arr))); // [[], [1]]
arr = [1,2]
console.log(JSON.stringify(subsets(arr))); // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(JSON.stringify(subsets(arr))); // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

// your code here
function subsets(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return [[]]; // base

  let el = arr.slice(-1)
  let prev = subsets(arr.slice(0, -1))
  return prev.concat(addEl(prev,el))
  //can be instead iterative: return prev.concat(prev.map(x => x.concat([el])));  
}

function addEl(arrA, el) {
  let firstEl = arrA[0];
  let rest = arrA.slice(1)

  if (arrA.length === 1) return [firstEl.concat(el)]; // base

  return [firstEl.concat(el)].concat(addEl(rest, el)) 
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple single-function recursion stores current working state in a second parameter, defaulting it to `[]`, and then, on each call with remaining items, removes that items, and splits in two recursive calls, one in we don't add the item to our working state, one in which we do.  When there are no remaining items, we simply return our working state, wrapped in one additional level of array.  It might look like this:

```js
const subsets = ([x, ...xs], ys = []) =>
  x == undefined
    ? [ys]
  : [...subsets (xs, ys), ...subsets (xs, [...ys, x])]

console .log (subsets ([1, 2, 3]))
```

We can visualize the tree of calls like this, with `[<xs>]-[<ys>]` at each node:

```
                              [1, 2, 3]-[]
                                   |
               ,-------------------+-------------------,
            [2, 3]-[]                              [2, 3]-[1]
               |                                        |
       ,-------+--------,                   ,-----------+------------,
    [3]-[]           [3]-[2]             [3]-[1]                [3]-[1, 2]
       |                |                   |                        |
  ,----+---,       ,----+----,         ,----+-----,           ,------+------,
[]-[]    []-[3]  []-[2]   []-[2, 3]  []-[1]   []-[1, 3]   []-[1, 2]   []-[1, 2, 3]
    \_____   \____   \_         \       /        __/        ___/       _____/  
          \____   \_   \_        |     |       _/      ____/    ______/
               \    \    \       |     |      /       /        /
               [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: That's absolutely amazing! Fantastic! I've expected something like this, but with some set of `ifs` . And this is just base case/recursive case/recursive step and nothing more. I still cannot understand some details, how it works, but will make some debug until fully master this. Greatly appreciate @Scott Sauyet!

Comment: Slight nitpick, `ys .concat (x)` should be `ys .concat ([x])` because if you were to call something like `subsets ([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`, the current code would flatten the combinations.

Comment: Or just `[...ys, x]`, since you're already using spread syntax everywhere else ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I had `[...ys, x]` originally.  Not sure why I changed it.  I'll put it back when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Note: for non-unique input arrays, this can give duplicate results, e.g. `[1, 1, 2]` gives `[1, 2]` twice and `[1]` twice. You may want to filter the output, depending on the use case.

Answer (score 2):

You were quite close already with the commented-out code, you just needed to use `x.concat(el)` instead of `x.concat([el])`. Or alternatively, `el = arr.at(-1)` instead of `el = arr.slice(-1)`.

```js
let arr = []
console.log(subsets(arr)); // [[]]
arr = [1]
console.log(subsets(arr)); // [[], [1]]
arr = [1,2]
console.log(subsets(arr)); // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2]]
arr = [1,2,3]
console.log(subsets(arr)); // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

// your code here
function subsets(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return [[]]; // base

  let el = arr.slice(-1)
  let prev = subsets(arr.slice(0, -1))
  return prev.concat(prev.map(x => x.concat(el)));  
}
```

Comment: I just forgot to remove the brackets. It is not the case.
`map` is an iterative method, like a loop. I intentionally replaced it with a recursive one. And now I think is it possible to use recursive cycle for both recursive tasks together.

Comment: @Dmytrq "*`map` is an iterative method, like a loop.*" - yes, so what? Your goal was to do this in just a single function, no? Notice that `concat` is also an iterative method. Sure, you can make your own life harder by defining all array methods yourself, but why would you do that?

Comment: for now I am studying recursion.And have to solve puzzles with recursive.It is hard,and a lot of tasks are much more easy with loops.But current goal is to master recursive thinking. 
Here [link](http://onecompiler.com/javascript/3yfjk59e9) is a similar task.Many solve it also in half-recursive-iterative way.But after some attempts I've proudly made it to fully recursive :)  And during this I've study some material on how to make recursion solutions. Now I just trying to understand: are these cases similar, and we just need to find similar way. Or they are critically different. Then "where"?

Comment: I'd recommend to look into purely functional programming then. Implement `map` yourself in a recursive way. Implement `slice` and `concat` yourself in a recursive way (on linked lists, though, on arrays it's pointless). Implement `concatMap`, implement `filter`, implement `reduce`, and you'll have found the shared structure between all these similiar functions. As for how many functions you need, it depends on the structure of the problem - subsets is fundamentally twodimensional. While one can always refactor two functions into just one by adding a "switch" parameter, it's rarely a good idea.

Comment: Look on @Scott's solution :) It's a top :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to [@Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673543/1541563), except this uses a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for `ys`, and it conditionally prepends the last element of `xs` to the rest parameter `ys` at each level of recursion, rather than conditionally appending the first element of `xs`:

```js
const subsets = (xs, ...ys) => (
  xs.length === 0 ? [ys] : [
    subsets(xs.slice(0, -1), ...ys),
    subsets(xs.slice(0, -1), xs.at(-1), ...ys)
  ].flat()
);

console.log(subsets([1, 2, 3]));
```

Here is a visualization of the recursion tree for this example:

```
([1, 2, 3])
 |-------------------------------+
([1, 2])                        ([1, 2], 3)
 |------------+                  |------------------+
([1])        ([1], 2)           ([1], 3)           ([1], 2, 3)
 |----+       |-------+          |-------+          |----------+
([]) ([], 1) ([], 2) ([], 1, 2) ([], 3) ([], 1, 3) ([], 2, 3) ([], 1, 2, 3)
 |    |       |       |          |       |          |          |
[[],  [1],    [2],    [1, 2],    [3],    [1, 3],    [2, 3]     [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Although I'm always loathe to use the last element of the list as a target instead of the first one, this is nice for creating a much cleaner output order than mine!

Comment: @ScottSauyet that was the intent :) Though I admit your approach is slightly easier to follow. The only thing I didn't quite like was the `== undefined` check for end of array, due to [reading beyond the end of the array](https://v8.dev/blog/elements-kinds#avoid-reading-beyond-the-length-of-the-array) performance implications, though I imagine both of our answers would be significantly different if the goal was performance.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that article, and only occasionally follow its advice; performance is rarely as important in my environments as is clean code.  And of course, if we were solving this problem for real, we wouldn't deal with the artificial no-iteration constraint that avoids `map`s.  I might actually write something like `const subsets = ([x, ...xs]) => x == undefined ? [[]] : subsets (xs) .flatMap (ss => [ss, [x, ...ss]])` or in dealing with that optimization, `const subsets = (xs) => xs .length < 1 ? [[]] : subsets (xs .slice (1)) .flatMap (ss => [ss, [xs[0], ...ss]])`

Answer (score 1):

**recursive generator**

To get a lazy iterable of the subsets, you can use a recursive generator. A utility `tee` function is used to "branch" the iterable -

```js
function *subsets(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return yield []
  const last = arr.slice(-1)
  const [exclude, include] = tee(subsets(arr.slice(0, -1))) // recursive
  yield *exclude
  for (const s of include) yield s.concat(last)
}

function *tee(g, n = 2) {
  const memo = []
  function* iter(i) {
    while (true) {
      if (i >= memo.length) {
        const w = g.next()
        if (w.done) return
        memo.push(w.value)
      }
      else yield memo[i++]
    }
  }
  while (n-- >= 0) yield iter(0)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1,2]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1,2,3]))))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
[[]]
[[],[1]]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2]]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

**map for free**

`Array.from` has optional parameters, `mapFn` and `thisArg`. We might naively write `Array.from(...).map(mapFn)`, but `Array.from(..., mapFn)` does the same thing in *half* the iterations.

Imagine we write `withStat` to provide some statistic about the subsets as they are generated -

```js
function withStat(subset) {
  return {
    length: subset.length,
    sum: subset.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0),
    subset,
  }
}

Array.from(subsets([1,2,3]), withStat)
```

```js
[
  {"length":0,"sum":0,"subset":[]},
  {"length":1,"sum":1,"subset":[1]},
  {"length":1,"sum":2,"subset":[2]},
  {"length":2,"sum":3,"subset":[1,2]},
  {"length":1,"sum":3,"subset":[3]},
  {"length":2,"sum":4,"subset":[1,3]},
  {"length":2,"sum":5,"subset":[2,3]},
  {"length":3,"sum":6,"subset":[1,2,3]},
]
```

**persistent iterators**

Above we use `tee` to read an iterable's values multiple times. Below we show `iter` that wraps a generator in a persistent iterator interface, allowing us to use the iterator multiple times.

```js
function *subsets(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return yield []
  const last = arr.slice(-1)
  const r = iter(subsets(arr.slice(0, -1))) // assign r
  yield *r // read from r
  for (const s of r) yield s.concat(last) // read from r again
}
```

For that we write an `iter` abstraction -

```js
function iter(g) {
  const computed = thunk(_ => g.next())
  return {
    get done() {
      return computed().done
    },
    get value() {
      return computed().value
    },
    next: thunk(_ =>
      computed() && iter(g)
    ),
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      let t = this
      while(!t.done) yield t.value, t = t.next()
    }
  }
}
```

Which depends on a `thunk` abstraction -

```js
function thunk(f) {
  const nil = Symbol()
  let computed = nil
  return _ => {
    if (computed === nil) computed = f()
    return computed
  }
}
```

Hopefully you can begin to see how data abstraction allows us to write higher-level programs and keep complexity under control.

```js
function *subsets(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) return yield []
  const last = arr.slice(-1)
  const r = iter(subsets(arr.slice(0, -1)))
  yield *r
  for (const s of r) yield s.concat(last)
}

function iter(g) {
  let computed = thunk(_ => g.next())
  return {
    get done() {
      return computed().done
    },
    get value() {
      return computed().value
    },
    next: thunk(_ =>
      computed() && iter(g)
    ),
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      let t = this
      while(!t.done) yield t.value, t = t.next()
    }
  }
}

function thunk(f) {
  const nil = Symbol()
  let computed = nil
  return _ => {
    if (computed === nil) computed = f()
    return computed
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1,2]))))
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(subsets([1,2,3]))))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
[[]]
[[],[1]]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2]]
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Nice formatting :) I will note.
I didn't understand all this nice code, but it obviously uses iterative :) And my current task is about mastering how to do recursive solutions (not sure what for :), but this in my program)

Comment: @Dmytrq `subsets` is recursive. `tee` is just an optimization to work with JavaScripts mutable iterators, a consequence of using generators. I included an alternative `iter` abstraction that gives us immutable iterators in another way.

Comment: Your code is awesome :) and I am sure it works cool :)
I just searched for clean recursive solution, and @Scott Sauyet brings even more then I've expected :) Will work on it to master the approach :)