# Conditional cartesian product of multiple arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

What I am trying to do might be way too complicated than I expect. The premise of the problem is as follows:

Given:

- `let params = [[1,2,3], ["A","B","C"], [10,11,12]]` and
- `let pairRestrictions: {0:{2:{1:["A","B"]}}}`

Where the first:

- key 0: index of the parameter
- key 2: value of the first parameter
- key 1: index of the second parameter
- `["A","B"]` : potential values second parameter can get.

I want to write an algorithm that calculates cartesian product of `params`. With regards to the conditions given.

So lets say the function to create these combinations are called:

```js
generateCombinations(params, pairRestrictions)
```

This function should return:

```js
let result = [
  [1, 'A', 10], [1, 'A', 11], [1, 'A', 12],
  [1, 'B', 10], [1, 'B', 11], [1, 'B', 12],
  [1, 'C', 10], [1, 'C', 11], [1, 'C', 12],
  [2, 'A', 10], [2, 'A', 11], [2, 'A', 12],
  [2, 'B', 10], [2, 'B', 11], [2, 'B', 12],
  [3, 'A', 10], [3, 'A', 11], [3, 'A', 12],
  [3, 'B', 10], [3, 'B', 11], [3, 'B', 12],
  [3, 'C', 10], [3, 'C', 11], [3, 'C', 12]
]
```

Thanks in advance!

I can create the code piece for cartesian product, but I couldn't manage to have the conditional part in.

---

This is the current solution that I have implemented:

```
 function recur(combinations = [], i) {
  let res = [];
  if (i === params.length) {
    return combinations;
  }
  for (let p in params[i]) {
    let combinationsCopy = [];
    for (let c in combinations) {
      combinationsCopy.push(combinations[c].concat(params[i][p]));
    }
    res = res.concat(combinationsCopy);
  }
  return recur(res, i + 1);
}
recur(
    params[0].map((x) => [x]),
    1
  );
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please share the code you got so far.

Comment: @Camilo Hey! The code I am using is also found on stackoverflow, so I don't think it is useful, as it has no places where I can pull in the restrictions.

Comment: how `{0:{2:{1:["A","B"]}}}` is a pair restrictions? i didn't understand the format

Comment: I can only repeat: please share your code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are other possibilities of the pair restrictions? What if there are triple restrictions or unique restrictions, or multiple pair restrictions, ...etc.

Comment: The easiest solution is code that generates the full cartesian product. But before adding an element to the output list, check that it doesn't violate any restrictions.

Comment: Why no answer to my request for clarification? You seem to give feedback to answer, but then don't clarify?

Comment: Voting to close this question by lack of details.

Comment: You need to explain your "restrictions" better. I currently have no idea, how exactly those are supposed to influence the result, and it looks like I am not the only one here with that problem.

Comment: I was at work and was not able to answer. The restrictions should be one way meaning, 

if input 1 has value 1, input 2 can only have value A or B.

The restrictions doesn't need to be three way, and they don't need to work backwards meaning, input 2 doesnt determine input 1.

Comment: Hi, I see you comment here, but remember you commented to my earlier answer with a non-working input where the order **was** backwards. Have you changed your mind, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: It wasn't about the order, but having multiple conditions didn't work on my end. I might have mis-wrote aswell.

Comment: You gave me this input example: `{ 2: { 10: { 1: ["A"] } } };`. Are you saying this is invalid input, or is it valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: switched to a more efficient implementation of `cartesian`.

We can turn your restrictions into an array of predicate functions, and then filter the result of calling a `cartesian` function on your input to include only those values which match all of these predicates.

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) => ((kids) =>
  xs == undefined ? [[]] : xs .flatMap (x => kids .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))
)(xs && cartesian(xss))

const generateCombinations = (
  params, pairRestrictions, 
  fns = Object.entries(pairRestrictions).flatMap(
    ([k0, v0]) => Object.entries(v0).flatMap(
      ([k1, v1]) => Object.entries(v1).flatMap ( 
        ([k2, v2]) => (xs) => xs[k0] == k1 ? v2.includes(xs[k2]) : true
      )
    )
  )
) => cartesian(params).filter(xs => fns.every(fn => fn(xs)))


const params = [[1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"], [10, 11, 12]]
const pairRestrictions1 = {0: {2: {1: ["A", "B"]}}}

const results1 = generateCombinations(params, pairRestrictions1)

console.log('If col 0 is 2, then col 1 must be "A" or "B":')
console.log(results1.map(r => `[${r.join(', ')}]`).join('\n'))

const pairRestrictions2 = {0: {2: {1: ["A", "B"]}, 3: {2: [11, 12]}}, 1: {C: {0: [1, 2]}}}

const results2 = generateCombinations(params, pairRestrictions2)
console .log ('------------------------------------------------------------')
console.log('If col 0 is 2, then col 1 must be "A" or "B"  AND')
console.log('If col 0 is 3, then col 2 must be 11 or 12  AND')
console.log('If col 1 is "C", then col 0 must be 1 or 2:')
console.log(results2.map(r => `[${r.join(', ')}]`).join('\n'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I made the assumption that your restrictions were cummulative.  If you meant to include all those values that match *any* restriction, then you can replace the `.every` in the last line of the function with `.some`.

So, with a pair restriction object such as this:

```js
{0: {2: {1: ["A", "B"]}, 3: {2: [11, 12]}}, 1: {C: {0: [1, 2]}}}
```

we would get an equivalent following three functions:

```js
(xs) => xs[0] == 2 ? ['A', 'B'].includes(xs[1]) : true
(xs) => xs[0] == 3 ? [11, 12].includes(xs[2]) : true
(xs) => xs[1] == 'C' ? [1, 2].includes(xs[0]) : true
```

If we preferred a shorter but less explicit equivalent such as this:

```js
(xs) => xs[0] != 2 || ['A', 'B'].includes(xs[1])
(xs) => xs[0] != 3 || [11, 12].includes(xs[2])
(xs) => xs[1] != C || [1, 2].includes(xs[0])
```

we could replace the key line in our function with:

```js
        ([k2, v2]) => (xs) => xs[k0] != k1 || v2.includes(xs[k2])
```

Do note that this entire restriction configuration technique has a significant limitation: the values we're testing on, except in the deep-most arrays, cannot have arbitrary types: they must work as object keys.  That means, strings, numbers, and, I guess, Symbols.  Any other type would fail.

Comment: Wow this looks so amazing, for the restriction: the value will always be either numbers or strings. What is the time complexity of this, what I don't understand is whether we are calculating all possible solutions and then filtering out or it skips them while generating?

The reason the time is so important for me is, I am generating 1 to 10 billion combinations.

Comment: @boramuyar: This does generate all `n1 × n2 × n2 × ... × nk` combinations first and then filters them. Its complexity should be the same (multiplied by the number of restrictions.)  if you have restrictive enough configurations that you can't hold all the candidates in memory, then you can use a generator-based version of `cartesian` and yield the results only if they pass the combined filter.  That will be slower but will require only memory enough to hold the final results.

Comment: @ScottSauyet i'm honestly shocked you managed to get this working with the object encoding. slick use of `Object.entries(..).flatMap`, i don't think i would've seen that.

Comment: @Mulan:  Thanks. `Object.entries(..).flatMap` has become my go-to for a number of problems.  I do think the input structure could be defined much more cleanly, but I never thought much more about it after I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

**maybe not objects**

Conditional logic and boolean expressions can represent complex ideas that would be difficult to capture entirely in an object-based encoding -

> If col 0 is 2, then col 1 must be "A" or "B":
>
> ```js
> let pairRestrictions: {0:{2:{1:["A","B"]}}}
> ```

The natural way to capture conditional logic in JavaScript is a function -

```js
function *myfilter(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p) {  // destructure columns
    if (x == 2)
      if (y != "A" && y != "B") // or !["A","B"].includes(y), 
        continue
    yield [x, y, z]
  }
}
```

Using a no-frills `product` generator -

```js
function *product(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const v of a)
    for (const c of product(...more))
      yield [v, ...c]
}
```

Let's filter the product to see the result -

```js
function *myfilter(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p) {
    if (x == 2)
      if (y != "A" && y != "B")
        continue
    yield [x, y, z]    
  }
}

function *product(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const v of a)
    for (const c of product(...more))
      yield [v, ...c]
}

const data = [[1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"], [10, 11, 12]]

for (const p of myfilter(product(...data)))
  console.log(p.join(","))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
1,A,10
1,A,11
1,A,12
1,B,10
1,B,11
1,B,12
1,C,10
1,C,11
1,C,12
2,A,10
2,A,11
2,A,12
2,B,10
2,B,11
2,B,12
3,A,10
3,A,11
3,A,12
3,B,10
3,B,11
3,B,12
3,C,10
3,C,11
3,C,12
```

**logical implication**

We used negation above to filter out, but maybe you were thinking about it more *"if x = .. then if y = .."*, that is [logical implication](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Logical_implication), ie x `implies` y -

```js
function implies(a, b) {
  return a ? b : true
}

function *myfilter(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p) {
    if (implies(x == 2, y == "A" || y == "B")) // ✅ positive
      yield [x, y, z]
  }
}

function *product(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const v of a)
    for (const c of product(...more))
      yield [v, ...c]
}

const data = [[1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"], [10, 11, 12]]

for (const p of myfilter(product(...data)))
  console.log(p.join(","))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

We can see the limits of the object being tested -

> If col 0 is 2, then col 1 must be "A" or "B"  AND
> If col 0 is 3, then col 2 must be 11 or 12  AND
> If col 1 is "C", then col 0 must be 1 or 2:
>
> ```js
> const pairRestrictions2 = {0: {2: {1: ["A", "B"]}, 3: {2: [11, 12]}}, 1: {C: {0: [1, 2]}}}
> ```

By contrast, implication helps us write positive filters and our expressions can be easily combined to represent more sophisticated logic -

```js
function implies(a,b) {
  return a ? b : true
}

function *myfilter(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p)
    if (
      implies(x == 2, y == "A" || y == "B") &&
      implies(x == 3, z == 11 || z == 12) &&
      implies(y == "C", x == 1 || x == 2)
    ) yield [x, y, z]
}

function *product(a, ...more) {
  if (a == null) return yield []
  for (const v of a)
    for (const c of product(...more))
      yield [v, ...c]
}

const data = [[1, 2, 3], ["A", "B", "C"], [10, 11, 12]]

for (const p of myfilter(product(...data)))
  console.log(p.join(","))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```
1,A,10
1,A,11
1,A,12
1,B,10
1,B,11
1,B,12
1,C,10
1,C,11
1,C,12
2,A,10
2,A,11
2,A,12
2,B,10
2,B,11
2,B,12
3,A,11
3,A,12
3,B,11
3,B,12
```

**freedom to think freely**

Or if you're thinking in terms of negation, you could write it this way and achieve the same thing -

```js
function *myfilter(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p) {
    if (x == 2)
      if (y != "A" && y != "B")
        continue
    if (x == 3)
      if (z != 11 && z != 12)
        continue 
    if (y == "C")
      if(x != 1 && x != 2)
        continue
    yield [x, y, z]    
  }
}
```

**flexibility**

Ability to compose (decompose implied!) filters allows added flexibility, and potential to order when sequence may be important -

```js
function *filter1(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p)
    if (
      implies(x == 2, y == "A" || y == "B") &&
      implies(x == 3, z == 11 || z == 12)
    ) yield [x, y, z]
}

function *filter2(p) {
  for (const [x, y, z] of p) {
    if (y == "C")
      if(x != 1 && x != 2)
        continue
    yield [x, y, z]    
  }
}
```

```js
for (const [x,y,z] of filter1(filter2(product(...input))))
  // ...

for (const [x,y,z] of filter2(filter1(product(...input))))
  // ...
```

**generators**

Even though you see multiple `for` loops, generators are run lazily and so each yielded value is processed ad hoc. This makes them a good choice for combinatorics or other large data sets where the caller gains immediate access to elements as they become available. By contrast, an array is finite and must be computed in full before the caller gains access to any element.

Still there's an optimization for the `product` function we've been using! See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668418/633183) for details.