# There is a lock of 4-digit PIN. The digits to be chosen from 0-5 for the keys. Find all possible combinations of keys

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

The problem goes like this:

There is a lock of 4-digit PIN. The digits have to be chosen from the digits `0-5` for the key to unlock.

We need to Find all possible combination like `0001, 0002, 0003, 0004`, and so on.

**EDIT**
Have posted my attempt in the answer.

Comment: With digits 0-5, just count normally, then convert to base 6. Stop when you get to 5555 (base 6). Don't forget to add leading zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array for the digits and increment the earlier digits until you find one that was not 9, just like you increment numbers in general:

```js
let array = [0, 0, 0, 0];
let output = [];
do {
    output.push(array.join(""));
    let digitIndex = 3;
    while ((digitIndex >= 0) && (!(array[digitIndex] = (array[digitIndex] + 1) % 6))) digitIndex--;
} while (array[0] + array[1] + array[2] + array[3]);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Just a slight problem. The output here seems to contain the digits 6, 7, 8 as well. But we need to find the combination from `0-5` perhaps `% 6` ?

Comment: @ABGR yes, indeed. Sorry about that. Edited my answer and implemented the fix. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

A simple recursion solves this:

```js
const combos = (alphabet, length) =>
  length <= 0
    ? [""]
    : combos(alphabet, length - 1).flatMap(s => alphabet.map(a => s + a))

const results = combos(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 4)
console.log(results.join('\n'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The recursion bottoms out when we want no further characters (`length <= 0`), and we just return an array containing the empty string.

In all other cases, we recursively calculate the `length - 1`-sized prefixes, and for each one, append every character in the alphabet.

Comment: Thanks.  While This really looks simpler I'm unsure how this is an optimized version of what I wrote.

Comment: It's not.  It's an independent implementation.  The optimization point in comments on your answer is simply about the number of calls made in two different styles.

Comment: You me smiling by achieving lexicographical order with `s + a` (works because `alphabet` stays the same). I started writing generic `product` which has too many ways to shoot yourself in the foot that I just cut the post short 

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple product generator -

```js
function *product(...p) {
  if (p.length == 0) return yield []
  for (const tail of product(...p.slice(1)))
    for (const head of p[0])
      yield [head, ...tail]
}

const digits = "012345"

for (const c of product(digits, digits, digits, digits))
  document.write(c.join("") + "\n")
```

with TypeScript -

```
function *product<T>(...p: Array<Iterable<T>>): Generator<Array<T>> {
  if (p.length == 0) return
  for (const tail of product(...p.slice(1)))
    for (const head of p[0])
      yield [head, ...tail]
}
```

Avoiding duplicate computation for recursive programs adds an extra challenge. For generators, one solution is to use a generic `tee` optimizer, as implemented in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711373/633183).

Another option is to use persistent iterators, using an `iter` technique presented in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73668418/633183).

Comment: Nice, as always.  I am a bit bothered by `digits, digits, digits, digits`, though.  It sounds like someone altering the Monty Python [spam sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrZyZn5nVks).  :-)

Comment: haha, maybe `...Array(4).fill(digits)` then ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). This is a very different solution, and probably more for the curious than something you'd actually use "in production".

We first build an object, which maps the wanted numbers to itself. This circular object is then traversed by object-scan iteratively to the desired depth.

Building of the object is very straight forward, this could also be written statically as `const obj = {}; Object.assign(obj, { 0: obj, 1: obj, ... }`

The object-scan parameters do the following:

- `needles` (`['**']`): Traverses any and all keys of input iteratively until the scan is either aborted or we run out of keys (second condition can never happen for our circular input)
- `breakFn`: Aborts traversal when we reach the desired target depth, without this we would never terminate.
- `filterFn`: We only return results found at our target depth (without this we would also return pins with fewer digits, e.g. `000`)
- `rtn`: We want to join the keys and return as a string, without this the output would be `[0, 0, 0, 0]` instead of `0000`.
- `reverse`: Not necessary, but this generates the output ascending, starting with `0000`, otherwise we would start with `5555`

Here are some cool things this allows one to do:

- We can easily iterate over other values, e.g. letters or even words
- We can traversal backwards and forwards
- We can easily exclude pin ranges, e.g. to skip all pins that have a 2 or 4 in the third position, we could use the needles `['**', '!*.*.{2,4}.*']`, etc
- We can generate pins of various length (e.g. 3 and four digits long)

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@19.0.5/lib/index.min.js';

const digits = 6;
const length = 4;
const reverse = false;

const data = Array(digits).fill().reduce((p, _, idx) => p[idx] = p, {});
console.log(data);
/* => <ref *1> { 
'0': [Circular *1], '1': [Circular *1], '2': [Circular *1], 
'3': [Circular *1], '4': [Circular *1], '5': [Circular *1]
} */

const scanner = objectScan(['**'], {
  breakFn: ({ depth }) => depth === length,
  filterFn: ({ depth }) => depth === length,
  rtn: ({ key }) => key.join(''),
  reverse
});

const result = scanner(data);
console.log(result);
/* => [
  '0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0010',
  '0011', '0012', '0013', '0014', '0015', '0020', '0021',
  '0022', '0023', '0024', '0025', '0030', '0031', '0032',
  '0033', '0034', '0035', '0040', '0041', '0042', '0043',
  '0044', '0045', '0050', '0051', '0052', '0053', '0054',
  '0055', '0100', '0101', '0102', '0103', '0104', '0105',
  '0110', '0111', '0112', '0113', '0114', '0115', '0120',
  '0121', '0122', '0123', '0124', '0125', '0130', '0131',
  '0132', '0133', '0134', '0135', '0140', '0141', '0142',
  '0143', '0144', '0145', '0150', '0151', '0152', '0153',
  '0154', '0155', '0200', '0201', '0202', '0203', '0204',
  '0205', '0210', '0211', '0212', '0213', '0214', '0215',
  '0220', '0221', '0222', '0223', '0224', '0225', '0230',
  '0231', '0232', '0233', '0234', '0235', '0240', '0241',
  '0242', '0243',
  ... 1196 more items
] */
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: I really think this could use a more detailed explanation.  I've been away from object-scan for a while, and I really didn't follow it.  But the initial object is fascinating (and a bit frightening!

Comment: @ScottSauyet You are absolutely right. I've added some explanation as to what is happening!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach, I've probably made this more complicated than it has to be. I've concentrated more on using recursion properly (no global variables and the function returns the final result or a call to itself).

```js
function recursion(digitsCount, range, currentCombo, results = []) {
  if (!currentCombo) {
    currentCombo = new Array(digitsCount).fill(0);
    results.push(currentCombo.join(''));
  }
  const newCombo = new Array(digitsCount);

  let flag = false;
  for (let i = digitsCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (flag || i === digitsCount - 1 && !(i === 0 && currentCombo[0] === (range - 1))) {
      flag = currentCombo[i] === (range - 1);
      newCombo[i] = (currentCombo[i] + 1) % range;
    } else {
      newCombo[i] = currentCombo[i];
    }
  }
  results = [...results, newCombo.join('')];
  if (newCombo.every((n) => n === (range - 1))) {
    return results;
  }
  return recursion(digitsCount, range, newCombo, results);
}


const range = 6; // from 0 to 5 there are 6 digits
const digitsCount = 4;

console.log(recursion(digitsCount, range));
```

The `for` loop in there is required (or, at least, another recursive function) if the `digitsCount` can be variable.

The main driver of this approach is using modulus (`%`) and the `flag` variable to make the counting `range` based (in this case, **5** based).

Answer (score -2):

Here's how to approach the problem recursively.

We need to divide the problems into sub problems and find the solution to *smallest* subproblem we could solve.

That gives our base case, i.e, for `0` digit pin we'll have `""`

Now lets break the problem into sub problems and attempt to solve that.
We try the first digit of the pin with `0`, then we only have to solve the problem for the remaining three digits. Same goes if the first digit we try with `1` and so on.

So let's proceed with this

```js
function findAllCombo(){    
  var res=[];
  var locks = new Array(4);
  function computeRecursively(newStr="", startIndex=0){
  
     //Base case
     if(startIndex === locks.length){
        res.push(newStr);
        return res;
      }

      // The digits have to be choosen form 0-5. So we recursively call for each of the 
      // digits.

       for(let i=0; i<=5; i++){
           computeRecursively(newStr+i, startIndex+1);
       }
      
      return res;
  
  }

  //This defines the lock- place to hold each digit
  
  return computeRecursively("", 0)
}

console.log(findAllCombo())
```

Comment: Is this AI? It doesn't make that much sense, for example, you're calling the `computeRecursively` function 259 times for no reason (that is how long it will take for the `newStr` string to reach a length of 4 characters, the same length as `locks`).

Comment: No, I'm saying that this is more then brute force, you're calling the `computeRecursively` more times (259 times more in this case) than there are possible combination.

Comment: @Titus: this is simply an unoptimized version.  You would have the same behavior in my simpler version if you replaced the recursive step (`sequences(alphabet, length - 1).flatMap(s => alphabet.map(a => s + a))`) with one that flipped the processing order (`alphabet.flatMap(a => sequences(alphabet, length - 1).map(s => s + a))`).  While finding such issues is an important part of development, getting a working solution as the OP did, is paramount.

Comment: Note that `locks` is not changing between recursive calls, so could probably be kept parallel to `res` and not passed through the call chain.  More than that, though, it's only being used for its length, so it would make sense to replace it with an integer-bearing variable such as `length`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet That's right. Thank you. Also, I'm still comparing with your answer to see how the recursive call can be reduced by making changes here. Could you please edit here if that can be done without `flatMap`

Comment: I think both Titus and I were confused a bit by your code.  Looking again, I don't think you can really reduce the number of calls much, as you need to calculate all the length 1, length 2, and length 3 strings to get all the length 4 ones.  You can always use a combination of `map` and `reduce` in place of `flatMap`, if your environment doesn't support `flatMap`.  But if you're going to do what I did -- allow for an arbitrary alphabet rather than strictly `0` - `5`, then you will need some such construct.

Comment: Yeah there's no environment issue as such. Didn't necessarily have to code in JS either.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I don't really understand why the downvoters did.  But don't take it personally.  People have all sorts of reasons for doing so, some reasonable... some much less so!

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah that’s true. Also, I didn’t mean you :) It’s to people in general. But that’s alright.